# how can I implement youtube live streaming in my android screen recorder app to live stream my android screen over Youtube?

Tags: android, live-streaming, youtube-livestreaming-api, screen-recording, rtmps

I have developed a screen recording application. Now I want the live streaming feature while recording screen. I want this live stream on youtube. From my research I only found how to live stream using camera or how to just open live streaming intent.
Can you guys guide me in the right direction it'll be very helpful

Thank you for your time

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need a media server for live streaming, please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70400557/17679565) for detail:

```
Android(publisher) --RTMP--> SRS/Nginx--RTMP/HLS--> Android(player)
                            (YouTube)
```

The media server [SRS](https://github.com/ossrs/srs)/Nginx is actually similar to the YouTube-like platform.

About the live streaming publisher or player, you're able to use FFmpeg, OBS or ijkplayer, about more information, please read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358918/17679565).